# How to implement a PIN code screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-shape

**How to code such type of password screen design, while after inputting the password the circles should change or imageview should change..??**

**Login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter MPIN"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_circle1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_circle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_circle3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_circle4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_grey2"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_enter_mpin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
EditText enter_mpin;
ImageView i1, i2, i3, i4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    i1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_circle1);
    i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_circle2);
    i3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_circle3);
    i4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_circle4);

    enter_mpin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_mpin);
    enter_mpin.requestFocus();
    enter_mpin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    enter_mpin.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    enter_mpin.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onKey: screen key pressed");
            i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**circle.xml**

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#6ab17b" />
<size
    android:width="25dp"
    android:height="25dp" />
</shape>
```

**circle2.xml**

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid
    android:color="#505253"/>
<size
    android:width="25dp"
    android:height="25dp" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you some code to show? Adding a click listener to the buttons and knowing how many values have been entered should be straightforward

Comment: You could have the circles with a blank drawables as background and then as the user types you load the black circles as drawables. You should first make an attempt and if you encounter problems, you can post questions regarding your specific problem.

Comment: @cricket_007 have posted some code to look into..

Answer (score 15):

Use [LolliPin](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/LolliPin)

**A Material design Android pincode library. Supports Fingerprint.**

[image]

```
<com.github.orangegangsters.lollipin.lib.views.PinCodeRoundView
                android:id="@+id/pin_code_round_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pin_code_round_top_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/pin_code_elements_margin"
                app:lp_empty_pin_dot="@drawable/pin_empty_dot"
                app:lp_full_pin_dot="@drawable/pin_full_dot"/>
```

Comment: how can change the text of title. Please suggest me

Comment: if you are using this lib than go in **AppLockActivity** abstact class in that getStepText() method, now just change text **pin_code_step_disable** or directly using string.xml change these texts@SAndroidD

Comment: Thanks buddy it helps me lot

Comment: and one more thing how to change the pin keyboard text color

Comment: is KeyTextColor of KeyboardView? But it is not working

Comment: In activity_pin_code.xml file there is keyboard . I want to change the keyboard key color. Its default color is gray I want to change into white

Comment: This library is no longer being maintained and there is a crash in it when the device lacks a fingerprint scanner.

Answer (score 4):

When i added lollipin in my project i got some erros.
Then i found some more libraries that are awesome too.
Check these out:

1. [PinLockView](https://github.com/aritraroy/PinLockView)
2. [BlurLockView](https://github.com/Nightonke/BlurLockView)

Remember these are views so they are a bit more customizable.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

Using this code in TextWatcher:

```
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                switch (s.length()) {
                    case 4:
                        i4.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        i4.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
                        i3.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        i3.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
                        i2.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        i2.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
                        i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can make the code more simple and modular, use this tutorial I wrote: https://medium.com/@Lev_Sharone/create-your-own-customized-pin-code-layout-in-3-simple-steps-e36d560689f8

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this JAVA [class](https://github.com/Parveshdhull/android-pin). You can also create multiple objects with a single line each if you need many PIN Views. For example on the registration page.

Answer (score 0):

Add **implementation 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:pinentryedittext:1.3.10'** to your dependencies inside *build.gradle* file and keep below code in your login layout.

```
<com.alimuzaffar.lib.pin.PinEntryEditText
    android:id="+id/pass" 
    android:layout_width="250dp"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:inputType="numberPassword" />
```

[image]
#xml #android